# Building an app that records the last X mintues of you android device

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app that makes a video of your screen and only keeps the last X mintues of the video, i have found a code for running an adb shell commands from app:

```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

But i have looked for a lead of how i can keep the last X mintues with no luck, any ideas of how i can do that? or maybe its not possible without rooting?
tnx

Comment: Are you getting the video recorded? If yes, you have to edit the video after you have done or after every x mins.

Comment: i want it to record the last X mintues untill i stop it, and ofcurse it means it delets everything that was before X min.

Comment: In this case, provide new file name after every xmins. And also make sure that the Android runtime system will also clears out the previous file reference.

Comment: This app will be very memory and processor intensive and the battery will drain quickly.

Comment: It is not a problem, its for debugging purposes, so battery is not an issue, but when someone is manually checking my app, sometimes i need the video to know what happen, a log is not enough!

Comment: Google took away the ability to do screenshots of the screen to protect passwords from being recorded.  I doubt that you could do this through anything other than a bug in the syste,

Answer (score 0):

I am trying not to build but just to find an android app that when I press "record" the previous (2-3-10 or choose from etc) minutes already saved, in RAM I imagine.
You may know when minidisk created (let's say about millenium or before) a few MD players had that function, where you can turn on & off this feature: If you had it on, when you push the record button it was the last 6 seconds already saved.
The logic of that was really simple: When you record a song from the radio and you may miss the start etc for a few seconds and press "record", the MD had the last 6 seconds already saved!
So, if you had it on and want to record it, you already had a few seconds written and then with just a simple edit you can delete them and set the start time (and delete the previous seconds) and the endting time (with deleting the last seconds).
Simple really.. But the point is that apart it's not something new, is 100% workable & easy to develop and I am amazed that I have not seen EVEN ONE so far...
Is it this hard to develop such a thing for a camera and a mobile?

I am asking about the driving of course, to not make videos everytime I drive (and I drive all day every day..) just with the mobile in it's stand in the car.
So, IF someone makes this application I have two things to say to him to add -> 1st to let the user decide how many minutes before he's like to have already saved and if possible, to work as long as the screen is even locked.
Why don't give it a try? I know I will not use it but nobody knows that for sure, but maybe the one time I'll need it, at last I will know that with the "recorde" or "capture" or whatever, that it's capturing but in the beginnings of it I already have the XX minutes recorded already.
USEFUL very indeed for drivers like me that don't want to put cameras in the car & with my phone holder IF I had that application with that feature it would be perfect.
If I am missing something, if there's somewhere an app like this and didn't check it, I don't know.
But for the developers ....just thing about it.
It's very practical, simple and you can have video proof in a ..let's say crash event without putting 2-3 cameras but only with mobile.
No idea is a bad idead for a smart developer I thing, then whoever wants sits and writes it.

Thanks, take care guys

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).